# Successive rotations on the same object

Tags: python, animation, rigid-body-simulation

I'm currently working on a realistic butterfly flight animation and need to do several rotations on the butterfly wings using angles calculated by an equation. In total, I have 3 different rotations on the two upper wings and they are all on a different axis. When I apply just one rotation at a time it works, however when I put the rotations together the flapping gets all weird.

This is the loop where I do the rotations:

```
for i in range(0, 360):
    
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i)
    time = i / bpy.context.scene.render.fps
    
    angle_g = eq.theta(vel, vel_max, time, 'g') #on x-axis
    angle_e = eq.theta(vel, vel_max, time, 'e') #on y-axis
    angle_p = eq.theta(vel, vel_max, time, 'p') #on z-axis
    
    wing_l.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    wing_l.rotation_euler = (math.radians(angle_g), 0, 0)

    wing_r.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    wing_r.rotation_euler = (math.radians(angle_g), 0, 0)
    
    lwing_l.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    lwing_l.rotation_euler = (-math.radians(angle_g), 0, 0)

    lwing_r.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    lwing_r.rotation_euler = (-math.radians(angle_g), 0, 0)

    wing_l.keyframe_insert(data_path='rotation_euler', index=-1)
    wing_r.keyframe_insert(data_path='rotation_euler', index=-1)
    lwing_l.keyframe_insert(data_path='rotation_euler', index=-1)
    lwing_r.keyframe_insert(data_path='rotation_euler', index=-1)
```

This is the result applying just one angle and after applying the other angles:
https://indecisive-grapple-7bc.notion.site/butterfly_g_angle-717ce27bcb8b47b68a5a23ac0c8df820

This is how I input the other angles:

```
    wing_l.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    wing_l.rotation_euler = (math.radians(angle_g), 0, 0)
    wing_l.rotation_euler = (0, math.radians(angle_p), 0)
    wing_l.rotation_euler = (0, 0, math.radians(angle_e))
```

Once I put the other angles the problem occurs. I'm confused about the order I should apply these rotations in the code and if I am applying it on the correct way.

Comment: Euler rotations aren't really optimal for this. I'd suggest rigging the wings, and use quaternion or axis-angle rotation. You'd get more reliable rotation, but the equation that calculates the rotation would have to be altered. It might be possible to do what you're trying to do, however the last three lines of your code seem wrong. If you assign anything to _rotation_euler_ it replaces its current value. Could you try wing_l.rotation_euler = ((math.radians(angle_g), math.radians(angle_p), math.radians(angle_e)), 'XYZ') instead? The way you have now, resets the X axis to zero when you set Y.

Comment: That should be wing_l.rotation_euler = Euler((math.radians(angle_g), math.radians(angle_p), math.radians(angle_e)), 'XYZ') .

Comment: This actually worked! Thank you very much!